# How can I format a number in VBA to display as million with 2 decimal places?

Tags: excel, vba, number-formatting

I would like to get number display as million with 2 numbers after the comma such as 2.11 m.
My code works to get million only, however when I ask to get deximal, it retrieve the entire number.
Any help will be great.

```
Format(CStr(Sheets("Latest").Range("P" & i).Value), "#0.00,,")
```

I already tried to to change the format several time, and also vba.format or function to force text but without success.

Comment: In addition to andrewb valid answer, you might be interested in my late response by a simple format pattern, too. Feel free to upvote if helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you can do this with just formatting but you can always do something like this:

```vb
Function millionsFormat(ByVal num As Double) As String
    millionsFormat = Format(num / 1000000, "0.00") & " m"
End Function
```

to test it:

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim num As Double
    num = 2100000
    Debug.Print millionsFormat(num)
End Sub
```

output:

```
2.10 m
```

Comment: Valid approach; fyi: posted a late answer referring to your comment *"Not sure if you can do this with just formatting"* ... yes, you can :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Display two-digit decimal places for an amount that is represented in whole millions**

> *"Not sure if you can do this with just formatting"*

... Yes, you can via `0,,.00 "m"` *)

- *) Note that the **regional** country settings might invert the common English comma `,` and point `.` separators especially in European countries.

or similar to @andrewb 's answer via *vba function* assuming an input of e.g. `2100000` with a resulting output of `2.10 m`:

```
Function millionsFormat(ByVal num As Double) As String
    millionsFormat = Format(num, "0,,.00 ""m""")      ' ~~> e.g. 2.10 m
End Function
```

- *Note that in VBA string parts included by (literal) quotation marks need redoubled quotation marks within the string `""...""`.*

Comment: Thank you for this, it's interesting. It works in VBA but I tried to make it work in worksheet with the TEXT formula and that one was giving me the #VALUE! error. Found out it was because my thousands separator is a space and decimal separator is a comma, so the format that ended up working for me is "0  ,00"